# Log4j2.xml set default value to another variable

Tags: java, log4j2

In the log4j2.xml, when setting a value to a variable, is it possible to set the default value to another variable?

For example: I'd like it to first try `${env:KAFKA_BROKER_HOST}` and if that is not set, then set it to `${env:KAFKA_HOST}:${env:KAFKA_PORT}`

But this does not seem to work:

```
<Property name="bootstrap.servers">${env:KAFKA_BROKER_HOST:-${env:KAFKA_HOST}:${env:KAFKA_PORT}}</Property>
```

If `${env:KAFKA_BROKER_HOST}` is not set then I end up getting the literal value "${env:KAFKA_HOST}:${env:KAFKA_PORT}"

Comment: Your example works for me when I test it in a `log4j2.xml`! However, when I unset the `KAFKA_HOST/PORT` values, I see the literals. Does it work when you pass in the `KAFKA_BROKER_HOST`? How are you passing those Environment variables to the JVM?

Comment: I confirm - I also reproduced it, and it works for me. Call `System.getenv("KAFKA_HOST")` and `System.getenv("KAFKA_PORT")` to make sure you have those variables set in your Java application.

Comment: Ahh, it appears I had another issue causing this. Looks like when the variables aren't set, it returns the literal value of the expression